# Missing GIN support function (4 or 6) for attribute 1 of index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, btree, gin-index

I have a problem creating GIN indexes in postgres 14.9 and GIN 1.3
The following is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE assert.test_gin(col1 func.doc_sub_type[]);
CREATE INDEX ON assert.test_gin USING gin(col1);
```

And here is the results of running the above:

```
ERROR:  missing GIN support function (4 or 6) for attribute 1 of index "test_gin_col1_idx" 
SQL state: XX000
```

I check pg_catalog and public schema GIN support functions. 4 and 6 are according to the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-extensibility.html) are bool consistent and GinTernaryValue triConsistent respectively, which both exist in my pg_catalog but not in public schema.
Please help!!!!!

Comment: It's a document sub type identifier. defining a bunch of enums
```CREATE TYPE func.doc_sub_type AS ENUM
    ('ARTICLE', 'BOOK', 'PRODUCT'...```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You are the one true guru!!
You are right, that was the problem. I really appreciate your guidance and critical question and direction.  Thank you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I was wondering if there is any other way to fix this without dropping and recreating the type.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please add additional information into the question itself and inform the person who requested it using the `@` sign and their handle rather than putting information into comments.

Answer (score 0):

Errors with an SQLSTATE that starts with `XX` are data corruption errors. You should see if you can `pg_dump` the database, then restore it to a newly created database cluster.